# How to update a list continuously without freezing the UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Ok so I have a method that reads running processes, filters, sorts them, then displays their names in the respective listbox (running processes and not running processes). I am running this method asynchronous so that the GUI can continue to function while the process viewer continues to run until the program is exited. I am using a simple while loop to accomplish this, but the method does not seem to be looping. The method runs through the first time properly, but it doesn't continue running, it stops after the first iteration.

How can I make this loop infinitely and continue to update the listboxes?

Here is my method

```
private async void process_viewer()
    { 
        while (true)
        {

        Process[] running_processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process proc in running_processes)
            {
                this.process_list.Add(proc.ProcessName);
            }

            if (this.process_list.Contains("notepad"))
            {
                this.running_list.Add("notepad.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                this.stopped_list.Add("notepad.exe");
            }

            if (this.process_list.Contains("calc"))
            {
                this.running_list.Add("calc.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                this.stopped_list.Add("calc.exe");
            }

            if (this.process_list.Contains("cmd"))
            {
                this.running_list.Add("cmd.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                this.stopped_list.Add("cmd.exe");
            }

            running.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
            stopped.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;

            running.DataSource = this.running_list;
            stopped.DataSource = this.stopped_list;

            this.running_list.Clear();
            this.stopped_list.Clear();
            this.process_list.Clear();

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you use this method?

Comment: its called in the class constructor

Comment: Can you put some code after the delay to check if it is ever hit.

Comment: Ok stilgar I added a line to open a popup window after delay and it did work (and there was a pause), so it is executing to the end of the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @user3846131 So then keep checking.  Where does it start running into problems?  Where is the first place it doesn't function properly, or get stuck, or whatever?

Comment: ok so actually it is looping because when I close the popup... it pops back up a second later. So the issue either lies in the way the lists are populated and then cleared. Or its an issue just with the listboxes not updating. Hmm

Comment: You have a while true inside the class constructor? How does that work?

Comment: @user3846131 You probably shouldn't have those lists be instance fields.  You should probably just pull out the information that you're interested in from the process list and use that as the data source without storing anything at the field level.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's not a constructor, it's just a method.  Constructors can't be `async`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Servy is correct, it is just a method, however the actual method call is in the constructor for the class (which is not displayed above). But its just process_viewer();

Comment: @Servy i know constructors cant be `async`. Avelyn said in the top constructor that he's calling the method from a class constructor, not sure why you assumed i thought a constructor may be async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that whatever control you're binding your data to isn't actually reading the data from that data source immediately, and it is instead scheduling the data binding to happen at some point in the future, after which point you've already cleared the lists, resulting in the control being bound to an empty list.

There really isn't any reason for these lists to be fields in the first place.  You should simply re-create the list of processes (that you care about) that are running or not running on each iteration of the loop, bind those results to your control, and then remember nothing from any previous iteration when you loop again.

```
private static string[] processNamesICareAbout =
    new[] { "notepad", "calc", "cmd" };
private async void process_viewer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Select(process => process.ProcessName);

        running.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        stopped.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        running.DataSource = processNamesICareAbout.Intersect(processes).ToList();
        stopped.DataSource = processNamesICareAbout.Except(processes).ToList();

        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to do here and I think you are right on track. I am however getting an error with this.

+  $exception {System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
   at Proxy_Commander.commander.<process_viewer>d__2.MoveNext()

Comment: @Avelyn_Grey Then pass it a list, as the error states.  That's unusual in the data binding world, but the error message is straightforward enough.  Take a look at the operations you have avaliable to you to find one that can convert an `IEnumerable` to something that implements `IList`.

Comment: yea I got it, I added .tolist(); at the end, easy enough. I changed it on your code, once its reviewed and approved I will mark it as the answer. You're the bomb Servy, thanks!!!